# Jquery: Swinging logo

Tags: jquery

I'm currently making a website for an old school c64 group, and I thought it'd be nice to show logos that swing side to side like in the old intros.

I thought I had it, but it swings one way and then back and then stops.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
function right() {
    $('header img').animate({
    left: '680px',
    }, 5000, function() {
    left()
    });
}
function left() {
    $('header img').animate({
    left: '0px',
    }, 5000, function() {
    right()
    });
}
});
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The jquery cycle on the page stops as well, no errors in the console. Must be some kind of animation clash?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a problem of scope. Try defining the functions outside the ready event handler, like this:

```
function right() {
    $('header img').animate({
    left: '680px',
    }, 5000, function() {
        left();
    });
}

function left() {
    $('header img').animate({
    left: '0px',
    }, 5000, function() {
        right();
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    right();
});
```

Comment: Nope that didn't fix it, when it stops it stops the jquery cycle as well, no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was something to do with the animation queue. I added stop() to t animations and now it works. So if you ever want to have a swinging logo on your page, here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
right();

    function right() {
        $('#images img').stop().animate({
// Move the image right to the width of the container, minus the width of the image
        left: '480px',
        }, 5000, function() {
        left()
        });
    }
    function left() {
        $('#images img').stop().animate({
// Move back to the left
        left: '0px',
        }, 5000, function() {
        right()
        });
    }

});
```